# Spark inserting data into hive external table creating very small part files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way other than repartition(which slows the processing) to combine all 1mb files into multiple big files?

run spark code on 500Gb of data , on 100 executers 24 cores each, but save them into large files with 128mb each.
now it is saving 1 mb each file.

```
spark.sql("set pyspark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true")

spark.sql("set pyspark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict")

spark.sql("set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true")

spark.sql("set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict")

spark.sql("set hive.merge.tezfiles=true")

spark.sql("SET hive.merge.sparkfiles = true")

spark.sql("set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=128000000")

spark.sql("set hive.merge.size.per.task=128000000")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option-1:**

You can do `.coalesce(n)`(no shuffle will happen) on your dataframe and then use [**`.option("maxRecordsPerFile",n)`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143159/spark-write-to-disk-with-n-files-less-than-n-partitions/48143315#48143315) to control the number of records written in each file.

**Option-2:**

Using [**`spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=n`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704156/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-sql-shuffle-partitions-and-spark-default-pa) this option is used to control the number of shuffles happens.

Then use **`df.sort("<col_name>").write.etc`** will create exactly the number of files that we mentioned for `shuffle.partitions`.

**Option-3:**

`Hive:`

Once the spark job is done then **`trigger hive job`** insert overwrite by selecting the same table and use [sortby,distributedby,clusteredby](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy) and set the all hive configurations that you have mentioned in the question.

```
Insert overwrite table select * from table sort by <col1> distributed by <col2>
```

**Option-4:**

`Hive:`

If you have ORC table then schedule [concatenate](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionConcatenate) job to run periodically

```
alter table <table_name> concatenate;
```

If none of the methods seems to be feasible solutions then **`.repartition(n)`** will be the way to go as this will take extra overhead but we are going to end up **~evenly sized files** in HDFS and boost up the performance while reading these files from **hive/spark**.