# What are the SparkQL options for com.amazonaws.services.glue.writeDynamicFrame?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

In this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-format-parquet

it mentions: "any options that are accepted by the underlying SparkSQL code can be passed to it by way of the connection_options map parameter."

However, how can I find out what those options are? There's not a clear mapping between the Glue code and the SparkQL code.

(Specifically, I want to figure out how to control the size of the resulting parquet files)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such option to control size of parquet files. There is a [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187622/how-do-you-control-the-size-of-the-output-file) using coalesce though.

Comment: Yeah :/ Apparently the closest we can get is to set `repartition(n)` prior to write out, which'll then produce n files (per partition key combo, if you're also using those)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SparkSQL options for various DataSources can be looked up in `DataFrameWriter` documentation (in [Scala](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#parquet-java.lang.String-) or [pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet) docs). Datasource for writing `parquet` seems to only take `compression` parameter. For SparkSQL options when reading the data, have a look into `DataFrameReader` class.

To control the size of your output files you should play with parallelism - like @Yuri Bondaruk commented - using for example `coalesc` function.

Comment: Still not finding it clear. For instance, there's a write mode (append, overwrite, ignore, etc) option for certain operations. Can that be passed in? How?

Comment: I don't think you can set the `saveMode` via option. _Options_ are all custom parameters for [DataSources](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-datasource-api.html)

Comment: Savemode: `spark.write.mode(SaveMode.Append)`