# How to define minimum file size with AWS Glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

We have some AWS Glue jobs generating parquet files to one of our S3 bucket. I've read in many places to optimize my files sizes, making them have at least 128 MB [- this is one reference.](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena)

Can it be done by Glue itself, e.g. with an auto generated Glue Script?

Comment: What size are the files? Are you trying to make the files bigger to reach 128 MB? In that case consolidate them before conversion.

Comment: I have both cases, bigger and smaller files. I am consolidating them using something like: ```partitioned_dataframe1 = datasource1.toDF().repartition(1)```

but this is a manual process, I would like Glue to make it by itself

Comment: How many S3 requests do you have right now? Since you are using paraquet this doesn't make sense to me unless you want to go from 1000 requests per day to just a dozen. If you don't have a high request that also means getting close to function timeout (if you want to use lambda triggers)

Comment: Its not possible. But there is a suggestion in the post below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187622/how-do-you-control-the-size-of-the-output-file

Comment: Thank you for your replies, this post will help me then

Comment: @RenatoBibiano what direction did you choose eventually?

Comment: @ArielB we are not using Glue anymore

Comment: What did you choose then?

Comment: @ArielB we have created our own job, but now we would maybe have chosen DMS