# How to control the size of output parquet files in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, bigdata

I have a spark job that reads the data from the hive table.
Ex:

```
r = spark.sql("select * from table")
```

and I have to write the result to hdfs location with 256mb parquet files.

I am trying

```
r.write.parquet("/data_dev/work/experian/test11")
```

This generates 30MB files
But I need it to generate 256MB files

I also tried these configurations

```
r.write.option("parquet.block.size", 256 * 1024 * 1024 ). \
               parquet("/path")
```

Still, the generated files seem to be ~30MB files

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any direct way possible to control the size in Spark.
Please refer this link:

[How do you control the size of the output file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187622/how-do-you-control-the-size-of-the-output-file)