# Sorted parquet files for query optimization

Tags: apache-spark, sorting, parquet, parquet-mr

### Question Purpose

Sorting a parquet files provides a number of benefits:

- more efficient filtering using file metadata
- more efficient compression rate

There may be other benefits for this. There is a lot of discussion about this on the Internet. For this reason, the discussion of this question is not about the cause of sorting. Rather, the purpose of this question is to talk about ***how to sort***, which is mentioned in all Internet links with the least explanation (about 30%) and the challenges of data sorting are not mentioned at all. The purpose of this question is to get help from all friends who are experts and experienced in this field and to determine the best method (based on cost and benefit) for sorting.

### Brief explanation about Apache parquet library

Before starting discussing Spark, I will explain about the tool used to produce parquet files. The `parquet-mr` library (I use Java for example, but it can probably be extended to other languages) writes to a disk and memory at the same time when we create a parquet file. This library also has a feature called `getDataSize()` that returns the exact final size of the file after it is completely closed on the disk, so we can use it to achieve the following two conditions when we write parquet files:

- Do not make parquet files with small size (which is not good for query engines)
- All parquet files can be produced with a certain minimum size or fixed size (for example, 1 GB each file)

Since this library writes to disk and memory at the same time, it does not allow data to be sorted unless all the data is first sorted in memory and then given to the library. (But this is not possible with large volumes of data.) We also implicitly assume that data is being generated as a stream that we intend to store. (In the case of a fixed data, the problem stated in this question will be meaningless because it can be said that the whole data is arranged once and for all and the problem is over. But we assume that there is a flow of data, in which case it is important to have an optimal way to sort the data)

One advantage mentioned above for the Apache parquet library is that we can fix the exact size of the output parquet file. This is an advantage in my opinion. Because, for example, if I know that the size of Hadoop blocks is equal to 128 MB and the size of parquet row-group is 128 MB, I can fix the parquet file size to 1 GB. Then I know that all parquet files will have 8 blocks and HDFS storage will be used best and all parquet files will be the same. (Because in HDFS, when the block size is 128 MB, the smaller file will take up the same amount of space) This may not be an advantage for everyone, and we'd be happy for experienced people to critique it if needed.

### Parquet File Sorting Challenges

One point before we start is that we are looking for permanent data sorting because we are going to use it in the next thousands of queries. Almost so far, the above descriptions have identified some of challenges for sorting, but I will describe all of the challenges below:

1. Parquet tools do not allow you to write sorted data. So one way is to keep all the data in memory and after sorting, give it to the parquet library to be written in the parquet file. This method has two drawbacks: 1) It is not possible to keep all data in memory. 2) Because all the data is in memory, the size of the parquet file is not known and may be less than or more than 1 GB or any amount after writing, and the advantage of being fixed parquet size is lost.
2. Suppose we want to do this sorting in a parallel process instead of doing it in real time and stream. In this way, if we want to use parquet library, we will still have the problem that we have to bring the whole data to the memory for sorting, which is not possible. So let's say we use a tool like Spark for sorting. A specific cost we give in this section is that cluster resources are used for sorting, and in practice each data is written twice. (Once the parquet writing time and once the sorting) The next point is that even if we skip these two cases, after sorting the data, depending on the other columns in the parquet file, the amount of parquet compression for that particular column and for the whole data may change and increase or decrease. For this reason, after the parquet file is written, small files may be created or the fixed size (for example, 1 GB) may change. Unfortunately, Spark does not provide a way to control the file size (it may not be possible in practice), and therefore if we want to restore the fixed file size, we may need to use methods such as the mentioned link, which will not be free (causes to write the file several times apart from the cluster resources that are consumed and the exact file size will not be fixed):[How do you control the size of the output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187622/how-do-you-control-the-size-of-the-output-file)

Maybe there is no other way and the only ways are the mentioned one at the above. In which case, I would be happy for this note to be expressed by experts so that others know that there is no other way right now.

### Challenges In Summary

For this reason, we generally observed 2 types of problems in these solutions:

1. How to do sorting at a reasonable cost and time (in stream flow)
2. How to keep the size of parquet files fixed

For this reason, although it is said everywhere that sorting is very good (and the results of surveys, both on the Internet and by myself, show that it is really useful), there is no mention at all of its methods and challenges. I ask experienced and expert friends in this field to help me in this direction (hoping that it will help others as well) and if ways or points are missed in this explanation, please state it.

Sorry if there is a typo in some parts due to my weakness in English language. Thanks.

Comment: What is the format of the raw input you want to process? If CSV, you can do some pre-processing. Just split CSV into smaller chunks, say 10-20M rows (Linux split command), then sort them separately using another command: sort. Then depending on the size of your data either sort -m part_*.sorted or transform individual files into parquet

Comment: Our system inputs are data streams of Protobuf (or anything else) that are stored in parquet files. But as I said in the description, we assume that an infinite stream of data is entering the system. (Because sorting a fixed data set, no matter how heavy, costs once, but data flow challenges are more important.)

Comment: This is outside of my area, but probably you may look into i.e. Apache Flink. From what I got it does operate on data streams and has a concept of 'window' which should let you specify a chunk of incoming data to be processed, in your case sorted and saved as parquet. But since I have not done it myself you will need to investigate it further.